# I am getting star pattern output in single column

Tags: java

I am trying to print the pattern shown below:

```
*
**
***
****
```

but I am getting a pattern like this:

```
*

*
*

*
*
*

*
*
*
*
```

I am using nested for loops.

```
public class Patterns
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("enter rows");
        int n=s.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give some space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [easy java code,printing stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549688/easy-java-code-printing-stars)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `println` is adding a newline after printing the `*` on each line.  To fix this, use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` in the inner loop:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.print("*");` instead of println.