# Java - Scanner Class Cursor not moving to last printed line

Tags: java, eclipse, input, printing, cursor

Mainly a visual and user-friendliness issue, but I would still like to fix it. 
My code here with the user prompt and waiting for an entered string:

```
System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase: "); 

phrase = input.nextLine();
```

The functionality works fine and whenever you start typing, and the cursor moves after the ":" symbol, but I'm confused why the cursor doesn't automatically move there every time the loop repeats.

Comment: *"every time the loop repeats"* What loop?

Comment: This is dependent on the console. You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001335/java-gotoxyx-y-for-console-applications).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put input cursor after prompt java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502176/how-to-put-input-cursor-after-prompt-java)