# How to put input cursor after prompt java

Tags: java, input, text-cursor

I tried to emulate console dialog using java. The code is simple:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print(">>>");
            s = in.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        } while ( !new String("exit").equals(s));
     }
}
```

But when it works it puts cursor in the begining of line, not after prompt (">>>" in this case). 
Is there any way to place cursor after the prompt?
(Here is brief video to show what I mean https://youtu.be/6QA6849hR9A)

Comment: I THINK that's just the IDE's problem, it happens with me too, but i don't know

Comment: try it in a DOS window instead

Comment: Thank you MCMastery, it is really the IDE problem. I've ran the code without IDE and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with IDE. When this code runs with cmd it works well.
https://youtu.be/BpIcJbUI7MM