# Displaying a command prompt inside an infinite loop

Tags: java

I've a command line application which awaits an user input. I want to display `>` as the prompt.

This is my code.

```
while(true){
System.out.print("> ")
// do stuff
}
```

The problem is that the `>` displays every time the loop iterates but the cursor blinks at the beginning of the loop, thereby making my `>` a part of the user input. I want the cursor to be blinking one space after the `>` everytime the loop iterates and also `>` not to be a part of the next line object(assuming I'm using a scanner to parse input). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just strip the `>` from the user input?

Comment: I want the command prompt to appear after the `>`. That's not the behaviour I get.

Comment: What are you using to get input?

Comment: Are you just asking how to change the `while` loop to make it blink after the  > ?

Comment: @c0der yes exactly.

Comment: Are you running the code in an IDE? If so, your question might be a duplicate to his: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502176/how-to-put-input-cursor-after-prompt-java

Answer (score 0):

If you really worry about "great user experience"; than anything that only uses the "java builtin" console functions ... will not meet that requirement.

So, if that matters to you, I recommend looking into the various libraries that give you "ncurses like" functionality, like [charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/), [java curses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) or [lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.out.print` or most other output commands, you're actually putting text in `stdout` / `System.out`, which your console will check to display said text.

It will not interfere with the user input which is transmitted via the independant `stdin` / `System.in`.

The problem is that these buffers are not modifiable, only appendable : once you've written something you can't come back to erase it, so making a prompt blink is not possible this way.

Some console might handle the BACKSPACE `0x08` ascii control character to erase the previous character, but I wouldn't rely on it.

There might be other methods that would grant you a read/write access to the console text buffer, but I doubt using it would be much easier than writing a GUI. I'd recommend either implementing your program in a language specific to your console (`bash`, `powershell`, etc.) or implementing a GUI.

Comment: If I put it outside the while loop it doesnt appear the second time the loop iterates, but naturally and that's not the behavior, I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Aaron that "> " will not be part of the user's input, you can verify this by adding the lines below just under System.out.print("> ");

```
String usrInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next();
System.out.println("Your input was " + usrInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking how to change the while loop to make it blink after the > :

```
 System.out.print(">_");
 while(true) {
   Thread.sleep(400);
   System.out.print("\b ");
   Thread.sleep(400);
   System.out.print("\b_");
  }
```

I wouldn't recommend to handle input this way, but it will get you the visual effect you are after.