# Printing Snowmen Ascii Art - From Codegolf (Non Competative)

Tags: java, ascii-art

Hi I'm currently attempting to complete [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49671/do-you-want-to-code-a-snowman) codegolf puzzle just for fun, I'm not trying compete and create the most efficient method. I don't even plan on uploading my final method.

The basic concept is to create your own snowman and print it following specific guidelines.

Anyway I can't seem to figure out how to print the arms of the Snowmen without complications as you will see:

*Here is the codegolf questions output method (where x and y are the arms):*

```
 HHHHH
 HHHHH
X(LNR)Y
X(TTT)Y
 (BBB)
```

*Here is an example of seed 33232124 (If your confused you may need to read the post [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49671/do-you-want-to-code-a-snowman)*

```
   _
  /_\
\(o_O)
 (] [)>
 (   )
```

**My question is:** how I would go about printing the arms when they take up a vertical space on the console and after printing arm x for example I am prevented from printing the torso in the correct position:

My Code:

```
System.out.print(h + "\n (" + l + n + r + ")\n" + x + "(" + t + ")" + y + "\n ("+ b +")");
```

My Output:

```
   _  
  /_\ 
 (o_O)
\
 (] [)>
 (   )
```

Here is the arms by themselves so you have a better idea of the problem:

NOTE: I put asterises (*) in place of empty space!

> X is for Left Arm
>
> Normal Arm
>
> ```
> *     or   " \n<" //code version
> <
> ```
>
> Upwards Arm
>
> ```
> \     or   " \\n " //code version
> *
> ```
>
> Downwards Arm
>
> ```
> *     or   " \n/" //code version
> /
> ```
>
> None
>
> ```
> *     or   " \n " //code version
> *
> ```

Sorry for any mistakes.

If code is needed I will add that, but for now is it possible is what I want to know or do I need to find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible if you port an existing answer to Java.

To reposition the cursor, try this: [Java gotoxy(x,y) for console applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001335/java-gotoxyx-y-for-console-applications)

If your command shell does not support the [VT100 standard](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm), [build your own library and call it from Java.](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0469.html) Or use the slightly fatter [JCurses](http://javacurses.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javacurses/jcurses/src/native/WinToolkit.c?view=markup) library (uses [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687410(v=vs.85).aspx)).