# Reading data from the keyboard for Windows command line without moving the cursor to the next line

Tags: java, input

How to implement a data read from the keyboard without moving the cursor to the next line console using Java?

Specifically, the command line Windows.

java.util.Scanner moves the cursor to the next line its method, just like java.io.Console.

As far as I know, return the cursor to the previous line in the Java console can not be.

```java
public static String Read() {
  Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  return Sc.next();
}

System.out.print("Turn of player: "); 
TempPlayerGuess = Integer.parseInt(Read()); 
System.out.print(".");
```

And I see:

Turn of player: 4

.

But I want to see:

Turn of player: 4.

Comment: can you provide sample input that you are trying to read?

Comment: @Exbury 
I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. [System.in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for accessing Standard Input. The input stream does not provide data until the user presses the return key (may be platform specific). Since all standard input uses System.in, I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking. Here's an example.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int readByte = -1;
        while ((readByte = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Read character code %d", readByte));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May it be somehow possible to convey character in InputStream to happen as I have shown above? @Samuel

Comment: I don't have experience doing that, but there are supposedly libraries for it. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001335/java-gotoxyx-y-for-console-applications