# Println that will not terminate the line

Tags: java

I don't want to break the line so I used `System.out.print(">>");` but I can't put `int` (`int number = scan.nextInt();` ) inside it and I can't also make `System.out.print("<<");` in the same line as the `int`.

I would like it to run like this: `>> 123 <<`

```
    System.out.println(" Enter Number ");
    System.out.print(" >  ");  
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("  < ");

    // like this  > 123 <
```

Comment: how about doing *System.out.println("> "+number+" <");*

Comment: Or `System.out.format(">%d<%n", number)`

Comment: Ok, reading again, I feel I did answer the wrong problem... you want the user input for the console (here `123`) to not add a new line ? So that you can add a `print(" < ")` on the same line ? Can you confirm please ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what OP wants. I think he wants to give the option to user to put the number between '>' and '<', e.g.
`Enter Number:
> (Insert number here through Scanner) <`

Comment: If my previous comment is answer positivly, then you should check the comment on [How to prevent the enter from making a new line in console after input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668031/how-to-prevent-the-enter-from-making-a-new-line-in-console-after-input). This is not out-of the box possible. FYI @LuisFerrolho, this is what I said in my comment several minute before you, I did notice my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Genevieve - can you clarify the situation based on the comments above please?

Comment: @notyou i wanted to put  '>' , numbers and '<'  on the same line but it's always like this : 

> 123
<

Comment: I provided an answer below which will output the brackets and user input on the one line. If there is something wrong with it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the user input *before* any of the printing, and then just concatenate the result with the `>`s.

```
System.out.println(" Enter Number ");
int number = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print(" >  " + number + "  < ");
```

Comment: he wanted his layout to look like this " Enter Number >". Your solution changed his intention :)

Comment: Oh, hmmm. I just went by `// like this  > 123 <`.

Comment: @MinhKieu `System.out.println(" Enter Number ");` this will not print `Enter Number >`. Don't search a mistake where there is none ;)

Comment: @AxelH - you did not update your comments when other corrected your solution above :) joker!!!